# How does COUNTA function works (google spreesheet)?

Tags: google-sheets

In a google spreadsheet I have the columns A and B populated with some data, then I have this formula to count the values in A if B=1:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(A:A;B:B=1))
```

Problem is that the formula is counting 1 match even if there is no value matching the criteria.

This is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak9RViY8FJE5dF9PN3F2ZVFsenk3TG1LZkZjS0d4MHc#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because the filter results in Error - showing the count 1 which is error...please try

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A1:A3,B1:B3=1),""))
```

Comment: Your formula has a zero, =COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,B:B=1),**0**)) replace it with a blank instead. Exact formula =COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A,B:B=1),""))

Comment: Doesn't work, I just copy/paste your exact formula and I still get #ERR0R!. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak9RViY8FJE5dF9PN3F2ZVFsenk3TG1LZkZjS0d4MHc#gid=0

Comment: Solved: the right formula is: =COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A:A;B:B=1);"")). Semicolon instead of Comma.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being counted and the other result replaces the error with "" which would also return 1. If you want an empty filter result to return zero simply omit the second argument...

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(A1:A3,B1:B3=1)))
```